# Inject an IEnumerable of interface in controller using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to resolve the dependency for the IEnumerable collections of the multiple class inheriting the Interface on the **controller**.

I want to resolve the following dependency during the application startup:

```
var notificationStrategy = new NotificationStrategy(
new INotificationService[]
{
    new TextNotificationService(), // <-- inject any dependencies here
    new EmailNotificationService()      // <-- inject any dependencies here
});
```

**NotificationStragey**

```
public class NotificationStrategy : INotificatonStrategy
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<INotificationService> notificationServices;

    public NotificationStrategy(IEnumerable<INotificationService> notificationServices)
    {
        this.notificationServices = notificationServices ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(notificationServices));
    }
}
```

What is the best way of dependency injection of IEnumerable types of objects in the asp.net core without using any external dependency or library?

Comment: register all the objects with the service collection at the composite root and dependencies should be injected when resolving the desired type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Register all the types with the service collection at the composite root

```
//...

services.AddScoped<INotificationService, TextNotificationService>();
services.AddScoped<INotificationService, EmailNotificationService>();

services.AddScoped<INotificatonStrategy, NotificationStrategy>();

//...
```

and all dependencies should be injected when resolving the desired type since the constructor already has `IEnumerable<INotificationService>` as a constructor parameter

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)